# Using an LT1357CN8 to amplify the signal of a 1.5 MHz frequency generator

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, frequency

I am working on a frequency generator to control piezoelectric transducers. I use an Arduino Uno R4 Minima to send data to an [AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9833.pdf) which creates my desired sine wave up to the required 1.5 MHz.

However, the output of the AD9833 is only 0.6 V, which is far below the sought after 30 V for the transducers. So I started researching signal amplification and found op-amps to be the solution to my problem.

I did the math (which you find below) to find one which should satisfy my needs, ordered them, however, now the signal is absolutely unusable. *edit: thanks to user "Andy aka", I know I will not be able to go directly from 0.6V to 30V, I plan on using 2 consecutive OpAmps with a gain of 10: 0.6V -> 6V and the second with gain 5: 6V -> 30V* this way I should be withing the bandwidth of the OpAmps

I ordered the [LT1357CN8](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1357fa.pdf) and used it in a closed loop circuit to amplify the signal from the AD9833. The following three pictures showcase at (relatively) low frequencies of 1 kHz the sine wave is very nice, at 10 kHz you see the troughs starting to be dented and at high frequencies the bottom seems to be completely flattened.

[image: low frequencies all fine]

[image: signal is useless]

How might I solve this problem? Is the op-amp limiting?

Calculation for an OPA828 which I found to be overkill for my case:

[image: calculation for an OPA828 which I found to be overkill for my case]

The schematic of my OpAmp circuit, Vsignal is the output of the AD9833, since this works fine I haven't added it in the schematic.[image: only using a gain of 4 right now for testing purposes. also I can easily increase the V+ with the power supply]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a schematic. There is a schematic tool available in this forum.

Comment: @qrk I have added the schematic for the OpAmp, I hope this helps

Comment: You can't get ±15V out of that op-amp, with ±15V supplies. The best you'll get, according to the datasheet is ±13V.

Comment: @ForzenikHD Try repeating your experiments with plus/minus power supplies. i.e., +7.5V for the positive power supply voltage and -7.5V for the negative power supply voltage. Single supply power topologies require extra care to make them work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> *the output of the AD9833 is only 0.6 V, which is far below the sought
> after 30 V for the transducers.*

That means you need a gain of 50.

However, the gain-bandwidth-product of the LT1357CN8 is only 25 MHz hence, if you want a gain of 50, the highest usable frequency will be 500 kHz but, you want 1.5 MHz: -

> *an AD9833 which creates my desired sine wave up to the required 1.5
> MHz.*

So, that's the problem.

> *How might I solve this problem? Is the op-amp limiting?*

You need a much faster op-amp.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The way I wanted to solve this problem is by having a circuit with 2 consecutive OpAmps, one with a gain of 10: 0.6V -> 6V and the next with a gain of 5: 6V -> 30V

Comment: @ForzenikHD yes I understand but, there's another potential problem if you expect the op-amp to drive a piezo directly. They have a fair bit of terminal capacitance and, that can make the op-amp circuit highly unstable (I'm also ignoring the current required to drive them).